# ajax: abp.libs.datatables.createAjax method with chinese input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
    $(function () {
    var l = abp.localization.getResource('tennis');
    var createModal = new abp.ModalManager(abp.appPath + 'Courts/CreateModal');
    //var editModal = new abp.ModalManager(abp.appPath + 'Courts/EditModal');

    var dataTable = $('#CourtsTable').DataTable(
        abp.libs.datatables.normalizeConfiguration({
            serverSide: true,
            paging: true,
            order: [[1, "asc"]],
            searching: false,
            scrollX: true,
            ajax:          abp.libs.datatables.createAjax(huake.tennis.courts.court.getCourtByAreaName, function    () {
                return {filterAreaName: "天河体育中心"};
            }),
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    title: l('AreaName'),
                    data: "areaName"
                },
                {
                    title: l('CourtNo'),
                    data: "courtNo"
                },

                {
                    title: l('IpCameraInnerAddress'),
                    data: "ipCameraInnerAddress",
                }
            ]
        })
    );
    });
```

this is my javascript code which try to call huake.tennis.courts.court.getCourtByAreaName api with parameter filterAreaName,when i use english it is all ok, but when i change it to chinese. it got problem.
in webbrower connection tab I got these:

```
filterAreaName=%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD&sorting=courtNo%20asc&skipCount=0&maxResultCount=10
```

I want some help to fix the chinese encode problem

Comment: You can build the parameter string yourself, then it won’t be urlencoded: `return "filterAreaName=天河体育中心";`

Comment: I use the value from html, then its ok now,thanks.
 
````
var chineseString = document.getElementById("idareaName").value;
````